# Script to Automatically Set Windows 7 Network Settings to Auto Obtain IP and DNS Server

Tags: windows, bash, dns, network-programming

I have a virtual machine that sometimes tries to set a specific IP and DNS server to reach, but I do not want it to do that. It messes with my ability to connect to the internet and my VPN. I program in Python and am comfortable with terminal and bash, but was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for a script that will set the IPv4 settings of my LAN Network to obtain IP and DNS automatically. Something that I could potentially just run at start up.

Cheers!

Comment: Network Connectionss - Properties - TCP/IP - Obtain an address automatically

Comment: @stark I appreciate the response, but I want that to be completed via a bash script or CMD as opposed to me physically having to do that each time. I've set it to obtain an address automatically before and it reverts back after a few restarts.

Comment: In that case you need to find the registry keys modified by control panel and fix them in a script.